# Why does vgs display this?

Tags: filesystems

I have a 5 disk RAID, that uses a version of Linux as its OS, where the volume (?) resulting from the RAID setup is called /dev/md8 and is 8.9 TB.

On this RAID I have two "shares" (I am unsecure what type of device or similar they are, but in the web UI they are listed as "shares"), S1 and S2. Neither S1 nor S2 has any limits on their size (they could use 8.9 TB if needed).

S1 contains 12 GB of data, S2 is empty. When looking in the graphical interface, it reports 0.1 % use and 8.9 TB free of 8.9 TB available. That all sounds reasonable.

However, when I run `vgs`, the output looks like this:

```
$ sudo vgs
  VG   #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize VFree
  vg     1   1   0 wz--n- 8.17t    0
```

**8.17 might be an issue of 1000 vs 1024 but why is VFree 0? Shouldn't that be ≈ 8.17 or 8.9 TB?**

Comment: Might you be confusing "unpartitioned" free space (what `vgs` would show) vs. filesystem free space? (`vgs` does not concern itself with filesystems, `lvs` should show 8.17t worth of allocated LVs)

Comment: @frostschutz Thank you. See my follow-up question here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/614128/how-do-i-interpret-the-output-from-lvs-and-the-content-in-dev-mapper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

8.17 v 8.9 is most likely difference between TiB (1024 base) and TB (1000 base) as suggested (8.17 TiB is about 8.98 TB).

Volume group is only a container, to see actual "leaf devices", you need to use `lvs` to display logical volumes. VG free 0 most likely means all free space in the Volume Group is used by logical volumes. Logical volumes are the top level block devices you'll see in `lsblk` or in `/dev/mapper/<vgname>-<lvname>` and that can be used to create filesystem on, mounted etc.

Comment: Thank you. I asked a follow-up question here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/614128/how-do-i-interpret-the-output-from-lvs-and-the-content-in-dev-mapper . Do you think you could have a look?