# How do I interpret the output from lvs and the content in /dev/mapper?

Tags: filesystems, disk-encryption, whole-drive-encryption

I just asked this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/614115/why-does-vgs-display-this) and got an answer but it led to new questions. I am trying to follow this [guide](https://linoxide.com/linux-how-to/encrypt-linux-filesystem/) to create an encrypted volume on an embedded device with a limited version of Linux (e.g., it doesn't have a package manager that can download readymade scripts for this purpose and similar) so I must do it mostly manually and I don't understand how to use the output from lvs and the content of /dev/mapper/ for this purpose.

Output

```
$ sudo lvs
  LV   VG   Attr       LSize Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  lv   vg   -wi-ao---- 8.17t 


$ sudo ls -la /dev/mapper/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root            80 Oct  3 14:24 .
drwxr-xr-x   16 root     root          4080 Oct  3 14:24 ..
crw-------    1 root     root       10, 236 Oct  3 14:24 control
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             7 Oct  3 14:25 vg-lv -> ../dm-0
```

**So, how do I use this information in the linked guide? What kind of device is `/dev/dm-0`?**

Answer (score 1):

In your example, you have one logical volume called **lv**, it is 8.17 TiB big and it is the only logical volume in your system. The **vg-lv** is just a user friendly name, **dm-0** is the system name and `/dev/mapper/vg-lv` is just a symlink to `/dev/dm-0` -- when formatting the device (e.g. to ext4 or to LUKS in your case), you can use both, it doesn't matter.

The guide you linked is pretty simple, so to create a LUKS format on it, you just need to replace *vg_server-lv_luks* from the example with *vg-lv* and run

```
cryptsetup luksFormat /dev/mapper/vg-lv
```

everything else should be the same. (Btw. formatting a device will destroy all data on the device.)

You can just pretend `/dev/mapper/vg-lv` (or `/dev/dm-0`) is a normal disk partition with a weird name.

Comment: I don't have the cryptsetup command. Are there anything else I can look for that can replace cryptsetup?

Comment: You can use [ecryptfs](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ECryptfs) to setup encryption on filesystem level, but you need to install ecryptfs first for that, so I'd recommend using cryptsetup which you already have a nice guide for. You can't replace cryptsetup in this configuration and you'll also need it to unlock ("decrypt") the device later.

Comment: I think I need to find a different guide because I can't install tools in this environment. There is no package manager, gcc and so on. However, there is a web gui that supports encryption, but for different reasons, that option is not available for me. Instead, I have to fall back on the command line. And I am pretty sure the web gui is just an interface to the command line. So what commands can the web gui use to encrypt the disk?